# Differentiate between tapping UITableView and selecting programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm looking to call different methods based on whether the user taps a UITableView cell or it's selected programmatically. I can't seem to separate them, however; the programmatic one runs everything in the didSelectRowAt indexPath.  Is there a way to use these more independently?

Here's my programmatic code:

```
func selectTableViewRowProgrammatically() {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: someVar, section: 0);
    self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition.none)
    self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what's your goal but check it out ```func setSelected()```  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623255-setselected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want the app to do when you select the table cell manually vs. when you programmatically call it?

Currently your programmatically way calls the same method that is being called when you tap the cell, i.e. `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`.

So if you want to do any additional computations, just add it to your `selectTableViewRowProgrammatically` method before or after you call `self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)`.

To highlight a cell programmatically you can call [selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614875-selectrow).

Note the `Discussion` part in the documentation:

> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a
>   tableView(*:willSelectRowAt:) or tableView(*:didSelectRowAt:) message,
>   nor does it send selectionDidChangeNotification notifications to
>   observers.

Comment: This is a great thought; thanks!. Unfortunately, I can't structure my workflow to make that completely work.  Some of the things I need to run when tapped are what I'm looking to not run when advanced via UIButton.  One other way I might be able to achieve my intended outcome would be to be able to "highlight" rows programmatically (whether they are selected or not), however I haven't found documentation that has worked for me yet.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, if I understood you correctly. So you want to highlight a cell programmatically? Have you tried: [selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614875-selectrow). Note the `Discussion` part in the documentation: `Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:) or tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:) message, nor does it send selectionDidChangeNotification notifications to observers.`

Comment: Thank you!!  I've been looking for this solution for days.  I didn't realize selectRow could be called without including 'tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)' within it. Once I removed that I gained the highlighting ability that I can leverage to solve my issue.  I'd be happy to mark this comment as the answer if you move it.